# Create custom menu on webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

How to create custom menu for webview when longpress event occur as shown in image at the top[image: From playbooks application]?

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String data;
private WebView webview;
private String clipdata = "";
private boolean mark_text;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webview = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    data = "The entire plan-to-produce process, including enterprise-level planning and scheduling, plant-level operations, manufacturing execution, batch manufacturing, and quality management. Capabilities for Big Data management and process integration support the use of real-time data from the shop floor to maintain batch traceability and genealogy. Embedded quality and compliance controls enable process manufacturers to manage exceptions and address nonconformance through corrective and preventive actions for batches. Leveraging mobile and cloud as well ![enter image description here][2]as on-premise technologies, this level of production control helps increase throughput, set predictable and shorter cycle times, improve asset utilization, and help ensure that inventory targets are met.</body></html>";
    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", data, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_search:
        Toast.makeText(this, "action_search selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return true;
    case R.id.action_settings:
        Toast.makeText(this, "action_settings selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

[image]

I have update answer with my code. plz check it and say how how can I disable this default action bar and add my own action bar but at the same time text selection functionality should work.

Comment: it looks action bars. you have to create it and hide it initially. and show it on long press of the webview's area

Comment: yes it's right. but how can I disable default actionbar.

Comment: No need to disable the default actionbar. just add the items in default actionbar and hide it. then show it on long press

Comment: how can I add items in default actionbar? can plz tell me in which method should I write code?

Answer (score 1):

This is called a [Contextual Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB), it's an overlay on top of the default action bar. 
There is a good tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html#tutorial_contextualmenu) which describes how to work with it.

To get own action bar to work there while still keeping the selection functionality is going to be tricky to say the least I'm afraid...

Comment: okay. but can  I provide my own selection functionality in webview?

Comment: Apparantly, there's an [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24841) for this with the android team. So unfortunately, you can't do this as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

To add actions to the action bar, create a new XML file in your project's `res/menu/` directory.

main_activity_actions.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Add the Actions to the Action Bar

To place the menu items into the action bar, implement the onCreateOptionsMenu() callback method in your activity to inflate the menu resource into the given Menu object. For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Respond to Action Buttons

When the user presses one of the action buttons or another item in the action overflow, the system calls your activity's onOptionsItemSelected() callback method. In your implementation of this method, call getItemId() on the given MenuItem to determine which item was pressed—the returned ID matches the value you declared in the corresponding  element's android:id attribute.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
             Toast.makeText(this,"action_search selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
           Toast.makeText(this,"action_settings selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.on

OptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

for  further guidance refer the official [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html)

Comment: I have put this code. still it showing default actionbar with copy paste option.

Comment: @nil what your actionbar look like ? can u share the picture and whole code u have implemented

Comment: also you should see carefully what code is in your res/menu/menu.xml file and what are you inflating in the onCreateOptionMenu() method

Comment: see my answer I have update it and uplaod picture as well as code.

Answer (score 0):

first create your own ActionModeCallBack then you need to create a class and extend WebView and overwrite this method:

```
public ActionMode startActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) 
{
    actionModeCallback = new CustomizedSelectActionModeCallback();
    return super.startActionMode(actionModeCallback);
}
```

update: look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22391169)
  It's work for me...